# How to use Windows live contacts api to allow users to import contacts

Tags: api, windows-live-id

I can't find a good, simple tutorial on how to achieve this in PHP / Javascript.

Basically the same thing FB has where the users specifies their hotmail account and then gives permission to FB to access their contacts.

As the API seems to have changed most tutorials simply don't work like:
http://livecontactsphp.codeplex.com/

which doesn't get the contacts (but authenticates and gets permission from user)